# Programmatically change content of xaml to change property of a control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is it's possible to change xaml programmatically through c#?

I'm trying to do is hide or replace a specific element, using a if statement within my class file.

The code I'm trying to manipulate is below, to be more specific I want to know how to replace `Spin="True"` with `Spin="False"`. I'm not sure how it should be done and believe that I need to edit XAML at run-time via code somehow.

```
<fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Refresh" Spin="True" Height="48" Width="48" Margin="0,350,0,0" />
```

So at the current state spin is equal to true so therefore the icon within the grid would spin, but I would like to set spin is equal to false during some form of if statement or simply within 5 seconds of the current form being active.

Comment: Learn about Binding. This is crucial in understanding WPF and will help you a lot.

Comment: Yeah I'm new to wpf, so it's a little confusing compared to winform.. probably doesn't help that I have the flu either lol, thanks for the heads up I'll have a look at binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to control your Spin property programmatically.

You should use the binding option in WPF , 
Please look into it more thoroughly since it is the basic principle of WPF and Xaml.

Here is an example of what i think you wanted to do :

Xaml part :

```
<fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Refresh" 
      Spin="{Binding SpinProperty}" 
      Height="48" Width="48" Margin="0,350,0,0" />
```

ViewModel (in case using MVVM ) :

```
private bool m_spinProp;
public MainVM()
{
    m_spinProp = true;
}
public bool SpinProperty
{
    get { return m_spinProp; }
    set { SetProperty(ref m_spinProp, value); }
}
```

Comment: It would be good to indicate that `SetProperty` is a method provided by some framework. If this person is new, they will probably not know about subtleties of each library, so providing working solution with simple `INotifyPropertyChanged` would be a nice touch. Also, you don't have to put signature in your posts. We can see who helps out ;)

Comment: As for the SetProperty  it is part of the Prism6 pack Nuget, so a simple search in case it won't compile and he can find the solution. I can add a complete WPF app for each question that i will answer but it will be a long and uninformative  for the person that asked the question. When i supply some kind of code snippet i am trying to demo a simple principle. As for the signature it is a simple closure to the message. Since i am also new here and really want to help people remarks like that kind of lower the mood.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the name of the control like?

```
 <fa:ImageAwesome **x:Name="imgSpine"** Icon="Refresh" Spin="True" Height="48" Width="48" Margin="0,350,0,0" />
```

and just you can check the property of the control.